# Adding class to existing html id using purely javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a div id with no class as so...

```
<div id="leftGraphArea" style="float:left; width:100%;height:90%;border:0px solid blue;">
            Left Graphing Area
        </div>
```

what I would like to do is add classes to the id by just using javascript. I know I can add classes to the div id in html by typing it in but I can't do so because I have code that creates graphs and there is no real limit as to how many graphs can be made. So basically, I would like codes in javascript that would result in the same html code as below.

```
<div class="graph" draggable="true"><header>A</header></div>
<div class="graph" draggable="true"><header>B</header></div>
<div class="graph" draggable="true"><header>C</header></div>
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

```
document.getElementById('leftGraphArea').classList.add('graph');
```

or [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

```
document.getElementById('leftGraphArea').className += ' graph';
```

Comment: when appending to className, add a space in front ;)

Comment: In `className` example, there's a missing space before the class (" topbar").

Comment: @JohannesH. He doesn't seem to have other classes on those divs, but true enough. :)

Comment: If there are no other classes, there is no reason to use += instead of +. If appending, always do it in away that deosn't break things when something is there already.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Came in today and I'm so thankful you guys helped me solve this!